# Xamarin.forms configuração

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin, xamarin-forms

Bom dia!
Estou tentando construir uma aplicação `Xamarin Forms` em um windows 8.1
Quando eu instalei o `xamarin` e tento começar um projeto, ele pede para eu adicionar um `MAC`.

É necessário adiciona-lo? e se for, eu preciso criar uma maquina virtual pra rodar o `mac`? Pois eu não tenho um.

Comment: Amigo, caso esteja tentando criar uma aplicação para IOS, sim será necessário você ter um Mac.

Comment: Olá thomas. é que eu vi que quem não tem um MAC, pode mesmo assim, criar uma aplicação com xamarin.forms utilizando o visual studio. Isso procede/?

Comment: Amigo, sim, você pode, você ira escrever a programação em c# ou outra linguagem padrão, porem, para você compilar a programação, você vai precisar de um Mac, exemplo, o mesmo se aplica para android, criar você pode mas para compilar, vc precisa do android studio instalado e os pacotes sdk do mesmo.

Comment: veja: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dn771552.aspx#NET

Comment: Entendi, obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Quando se cria um projeto tipo `Xamarin Forms` automaticamente são criados 3 projetos para três platarmormas `iOS, Android, WP`.

Caso sua intenção seja criar somente uma aplicação `WP` não é vantajoso utilizar esta plataforma, melhor desenvolver uma aplicação nativa.

Agora caso queira que sua aplicação funcione para aparelhos `Android` e `WP` basta ignorar a mensagem referente ao `MAC (É necessário ter um MAC ,ou uma máquina virtual, para desenvolver para iOS)` pode até desativar ou remover o projeto para a plataforma `iOS`.